# Using NSSortDescriptor to sort by date without time [Swift]

Tags: swift, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an tableview with an `NSFetchedResultsController` that sorts my data their dates. I have tried to implement drag and drop for the user to reorder their cells by changing the date's day based on the tableView section it will be dropped in (each section corresponds to a day). But whenever I do this I get this error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to move row at index path <NSIndexPath: 0xa62f3820381b6116> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0} to both <NSIndexPath: 0xa62f3820385b6216> {length = 2, path = 2 - 2} and <NSIndexPath: 0xa62f3820383b6216> {length = 2, path = 2 - 1}`

I think the root of the problem is the `NSFetchedResultsController` sort descriptor: `NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)` because this sorts by the date which includes seconds, minutes, etc. When I drag and drop between sections I only change the days date, not the time **How do use the `NSSortDescriptor` to sort by the date but without the time (hours, minutes, etc)?**

I believe this will fix my problem but I can not seem to figure it out. I tried setting the time (hours, minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds) to the same thing for each item but this still doesn't help.